# Centering HTML Content Inside Colorbox Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using Jack Moore's Colorbox.  I am having an HTML file open in an iframe popup.  When the screen is smaller than the width of the content, the alignment is always at essentially left: 0.

I have noodled around witch the colorbox css and I can't seem to get this one figured out.

[image: How it is]

[image: How I want it to be]

HTML:

```
<h2><a class="iframe" href="videolinks.html">[CLICK HERE]</a></h2>
```

CSS:

```
    #colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; text-align: center; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
#cboxWrapper {max-width:none;}
#cboxOverlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; text-align: center;}
#cboxMiddleLeft, #cboxBottomLeft{clear:left;}
#cboxContent{position:relative; }
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}
#cboxTitle{margin:0;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{cursor:pointer;}
.cboxPhoto{float:left; margin:auto; border:0; display:block; max-width:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
.cboxIframe{width:100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0; padding:0; margin: 0;}
#colorbox, #cboxContent, #cboxLoadedContent{box-sizing:content-box; -moz-box-sizing:content-box; -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;}

#cboxOverlay{background:url(../images/colorbox/overlay2.png) repeat 0 0; opacity: 0.9; filter: alpha(opacity = 90); z-index: 9999;}
#colorbox{outline:0;}
#cboxTopLeft{width:21px; height:21px; background:url(../images/colorbox/controls2.png) no-repeat -101px 0;}
#cboxTopRight{width:21px; height:21px; background:url(../images/colorbox/controls2.png) no-repeat -130px 0;}
#cboxBottomLeft{width:21px; height:21px; background:url(../images/colorbox/controls2.png) no-repeat -101px -29px;}
#cboxBottomRight{width:21px; height:21px; background:url(../images/colorbox/controls2.png) no-repeat -130px -29px;}
#cboxMiddleLeft{width:21px; background:url(../images/colorbox/controls2.png) left top repeat-y;}
#cboxMiddleRight{width:21px; background:url(../images/colorbox/controls2.png) right top repeat-y;}
#cboxTopCenter{height:21px; background:url(../images/colorbox/border2.png) 0 0 repeat-x;}
#cboxBottomCenter{height:21px; background:url(../images/colorbox/border2.png) 0 -29px repeat-x;}
#cboxContent{background:white;  height: 100%; margin: auto;}
    .cboxIframe{background:#fff; margin-right: 0;}
    #cboxError{padding:50px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
    #cboxLoadedContent{margin-bottom:0px;} /* THIS WAS '28px' WHICH CAUSED A BAR ALONG THE BOTTOM */
    #cboxTitle{position:absolute; bottom:4px; left:0; text-align:center; width:100%; color:#949494;}
    #cboxCurrent{position:absolute; bottom:4px; left:58px; color:#949494;}
    #cboxLoadingOverlay{background:url(../images/colorbox/loading_background.png) no-repeat center center;}
    #cboxLoadingGraphic{background:url(../images/colorbox/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;}

    /* these elements are buttons, and may need to have additional styles reset to avoid unwanted base styles */
    #cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxSlideshow, #cboxClose {border:0; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:visible; width:auto; background:none; }

    /* avoid outlines on :active (mouseclick), but preserve outlines on :focus (tabbed navigating) */
    #cboxPrevious:active, #cboxNext:active, #cboxSlideshow:active, #cboxClose:active {outline:0;}

    #cboxSlideshow{position:absolute; bottom:4px; right:30px; color:#0092ef;}
    #cboxPrevious{position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; background:url(../images/colorbox/controls2.png) no-repeat -75px 0; width:25px; height:25px; text-indent:-9999px;}
    #cboxPrevious:hover{background-position:-75px -25px;}
    #cboxNext{position:absolute; bottom:0; left:27px; background:url(../images/colorbox/controls2.png) no-repeat -50px 0; width:25px; height:25px; text-indent:-9999px;}
    #cboxNext:hover{background-position:-50px -25px;}
    #cboxClose{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; opacity: 0.7; background-image: url(../images/colorbox/x2.png); background-size: 35px; width:35px; height:35px; text-indent:-9999px;}
    #cboxClose:hover{opacity: 1.0}
```

Comment: Can you post the code ?

Comment: did you tried `text-align:center`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried text-align: center to no avail.

Comment: I could post the code, but it is the standard code that comes with colorbox.  But if it gets an answer, I can do it.

Comment: Original question updated with code.  Let me know if I did it wrong.....

Comment: Are you trying to style the contents within an iFrame? I don't believe it is possible to pass any external styles to an iFrame. I would love to be proved wrong. If you can control the content within the iFrame, `margin: 0 auto;` is typically the first CSS rule you should try to center align `<foo>`.

Comment: No....I am trying to style the container so that what it holds sits squarely in the center instead of to the left.